# Android Hilt setup with androidx.hilt

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

I am able to setup and run project with Android HILT following the [documentation about the HILT](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android)

How am I supposed to upgrade it to [androidx.hilt version](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/hilt#version_100_3)?
Do I need to add or remove any classpath or plugin?
I have tried removing both classpath and plugin for `com.google.dagger` but I get compilation error that Hilt is not found!

Not working

```
implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-*:1.0.0'
kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0'
```

Working

```
classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.38.1'
...
apply plugin: 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
...
implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.38.1'
kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.38.1'
implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-fragment:1.0.0'
kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0'
```

Do I still need to use plugins and classpath?

Comment: Can you share your `build.gradle` and app `build.gradle` code?

Comment: @DươngMinh added to the question